# How to put data over dots in R studio ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have data from the number of natural disasters occurred in the world from 1900 to 2018 and I want to do a line chart. I can do the chart, but I would like to make some changes and I don't know how to do it.

1) The horizontal axis shows the years in 25-year intervals, so the year of the last data, that is, the year 2018 does not appear. I would like this year to appear on the x axis.

2) I would like that over the dots the data appears.

My code is the following:

```
library("readr")
library("fmsb")
library("car")
library("normtest")
library("nortest")
library("moments")
library("readxl")   # carga de paquetes para exportar experimentos desde excel.
library("ggplot2")
library("stats")

total_1 <- read_csv("C:/Users/Alonso/Desktop/Tesis_MGII/Avance_mayo/escrito/number-of-natural-disaster-events (1).csv")
View(total_1)
print(total_1)
attach(total_1)
total_data<-data.frame(total_1)
View(total_data)
ggplot(data=total_data, aes(x=Year, y=`Natural disasters events`)) +
  geom_line(color="blue",size=0.9)+
  geom_point(color="red", size=1.0)
```

My actual plot is the following:
[image: Line chart]
Some hints?, Thanks in advance.

Héctor.

Comment: 1. See http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/. Look for "limits". 2. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html or another similar page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you can reverse the `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` to have the line draw last (on top of the points), and setting breaks as below should do the trick for getting `2018` on the x-axis.

```
ggplot(data=total_data, aes(x=Year, y=`Natural disasters events`)) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1900, 1925, 1950, 1975, 2000, 2018)) +
     geom_point(color="red", size=1.0) + geom_line(color="blue",size=0.9)
```